# C: Memory error while running program

Tags: c, out-of-memory

I'm trying to write a program that accepts strings (these are given) and then stores them according to their length in another array. After this, the program prints out the amount of the word who have that length. I tried to create this using this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *repeatStr(char *str, int count); 

int main() {

char arr[8][128] = { "Hallo", "Stewardess", "wat", "een", "fijne", "vlucht" };  
int groottes[11] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= strlen(arr); i++)   {
        char *word =  arr[i] ;      
        int grootte = strlen(word);
        groottes[grootte] += 1; 
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(arr); i++)    {
        char ret;
        int grt = groottes[i];
        ret = repeatStr('*', grt);
        printf("%d: %s", i + 1, ret);   
     }
}


void *repeatStr(char *str, int count) {     
    if (count == 0) return "";
    char *ret = malloc(strlen(str) * count + count);
    if (ret == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(ret, str);
    while (--count > 0) {
    strcat(ret, str);   
  }     
  return ret; 
}
```

the error I get is:

> Exception thrown at 0x0FD53B8D (ucrtbased.dll) in Oefening.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000061.

Comment: What happens? Is there an exception thrown? What is the stack trace?

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; i <= strlen(arr); i++)` I think you want `sizeof(arr)` here

Comment: @Alexguitar - I think he actually needs (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - Otherwise he's going to iterate over 8*128 entries :)

Comment: Does this compile? `repeatStr` expects a `char *` but you pass it a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Given this declaration:

> ```
> char arr[8][128] = { "Hallo", "Stewardess", "wat", "een", "fijne", "vlucht" };
> ```

The two loops are grossly incorrect:

> ```
> for (size_t i = 0; i <= strlen(arr); i++)   {
>     /* ... */
> }
> ```

Pay attention to compiler warnings, and turn them up if need be.  The compiler should be warning you that in `strlen(arr)`, you are passing a pointer to `strlen()` that is incompatible with its parameter type.  Specifically, you are passing a `char (*)[128]` (pointer to array of 128 char) whereas `strlen()`'s expects a possibly-`const` `char *`.

If you want the number of elements in `arr` (8), that would be what @NadavL suggested: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`.  Given that you have space for 8 elements but initializers for only 6, however, I suppose what you *really* want is

```
for (size_t i = 0; (i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])) && arr[i][0]; i++)   {
    /* ... */
}
```

That ensures that `i` does not exceed the array bound, but stops the iteration if you run out of words before you run out of array.  The latter would not be possible, so there would be no need to check for it, if you allowed C to choose the array size for you, by declaring it like this, instead:

```
char arr[][128] = { "Hallo", "Stewardess", "wat", "een", "fijne", "vlucht" };
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
char arr[8][128] = { ... };
```

can be changed to :

```
char arr[][128] = { ... };
```

The compiler can see how many elements you need so it allocates just enough when you omit the first size. In your case you're allocating space for 8 strings, while you're only initializing 6 of them, which could lead to problems later.

In your first two loops you want to check for the following condition:

```
i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
```

Arrays are zero-indexed, so if your array has `n` elements, you can access only the following elements:

```
arr[0], arr[1], ... , arr[n-1]
```

`sizeof(arr)` is the total memory occupied by `arr`. If you want the number of arrays in `arr` you have to divide it by the size of its elements, so `sizeof(arr[0])`

There is also an issue with the way you call `repeatStr` 
It expects a string, so I assume you want to call it with:

```
ret = repeatStr(arr[i], grt);
```

where `ret` is definded like so:

```
char *ret;
```

because it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

On the first loop, it seems like you want to iterate through the words in your array.

But instead of doing so, you're going to iterate 8*128 times, as sizeof(arr) will return 8*128 (you allocated 128 bytes 8 times - one for each word).

What you actually want to use is:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); i++)
```

That will produce the correct number of word entries in your array.

Additionally, you use:

```
char ret;
ret = repeatStr("*", grt);
```

But repeatStr returns a char *, and then you treat 'ret' as a char*, even though in the function context it's merely a regular char.

Change to:

```
char *ret;
ret = repeatStr("*", grt);
```

And it should compile and execute without memory violations.

Comment: using memset like that would just delete all the contents of the array, though true the array is too long

Comment: `arr[8][128] = { "Hallo", "Stewardess", "wat", "een", "fijne", "vlucht" }` initializes all of `arr`.  `memset()` not needed.